# How can I ensure a span always appears to the right of a textarea inside a div that might resize?

Tags: html, css

I have four divs and each has a width of 25% of the page. Here is the HTML code that I have:

```
<div style="display: table-cell; width:25%">
    <div>
        <textarea style="height: 1.5rem; width: 95%"></textarea>
        <span style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 0.5rem;">xx</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer `<div>` is one of four equally sized that are inside a `display: table-row` which is inside a `display: table`.

Is there a way that I could ensure the span with xx always appears to the right of the textarea and not below it. When the page is wide it appears to the right but as the size of the page reduces the available 5% for the span becomes small and it moves below the text area.

Comment: You can add 'float:right;' to the span.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` to position the `<span>` and also `float` the parent `<div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/ckxLzgdp/

Answer (score 0):

I'd try laying out the inner div with a flexbox layout:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
}

.container > textarea {
  flex: 0 0 95%;
}

.container > span {
  flex: 0 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: table-cell; width:25%">
    <div class="container">
        <textarea style="height: 1.5rem;"></textarea>
        <span style="display: inline-block;">xx</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css-tricks has an [excellent flexbox reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)